# User input prevents multiprocessing segment of code to work on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, user-input

The problem resolves around my multiprocessing segment not working when I have an input question.

I have tried many workaround to the problem but cannot find a solution, except eliminating the input, however I need it to allow others to interact with my tool.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import collections

choice = input("Do you wish to start program? \n")
print("hello")
start_time = time.time()
value = collections.namedtuple('value',['vectx','vecty'])
Values = (value(vectx=0,vecty=5),value(vectx=5,vecty=10),value(vectx=10,vecty=15),value(vectx=15,vecty=20))#,value(vectx=200,vecty=300),value(vectx=300,vecty=400),value(vectx=400,vecty=500),value(vectx=500,vecty=600),value(vectx=600,vecty=700),value(vectx=700,vecty=800),value(vectx=800,vecty=900),value(vectx=900,vecty=1000),value(vectx=1000,vecty=1100),value(vectx=1100,vecty=1200))
print("Start")

def Alter(x):
    vectx=x.vectx
    vecty=x.vecty
    Z=(vectx+vecty)
    return(Z)

if choice == "Yes":
    print(1)
    if __name__ == '__main__':    
        with Pool(10) as p:
            result=p.map(Alter, Values)
        new = []
        print("end")
        print("result Done")
        for i in result:
                new.append(i)

        print( "My program took " +str(time.time() - start_time)+ " to run")
```

Expected result is program completes.

Comment: Can you post the traceback you are getting?

Comment: Im getting no traceback, just a blank screen .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that windows doesn't have `fork` like Unix based machines. So each process of the Pool running on Windows **imports** the main file on creation.

So what happens in your program is that each new process asks for input and your programs tangles up with itself. It was a little unclear to me the location of the `if __name__ == '__main__':`, but the point here is that you need to keep everything that needs to run once there. Put outside of it only important stuff shared between all processes. For example, a working code on windows could be:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import collections

def Alter(x):
    vectx = x.vectx
    vecty = x.vecty
    Z = (vectx + vecty)
    return Z

value = collections.namedtuple('value', ['vectx', 'vecty'])

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    choice = input("Do you wish to start program? \n")
    Values = (value(vectx=0,vecty=5),value(vectx=5,vecty=10),value(vectx=10,vecty=15))
    if choice == "Yes":
        print("Start")
        start_time = time.time()
        with Pool(10) as p:
            result = p.map(Alter, Values)
         print("My program took " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " to run")
```

Gives:

```
Do you wish to start program? 
Yes
Start
My program took 1.9328622817993164 to run
```

---

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), under [programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines), section *Safe importing of main module*:

> Make sure that the main module **can be safely imported** by a new Python
>   interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a
>   new process).

Comment: Mind assisting me with my larger code, I cant seem to find where it is going wrong.

Comment: mmm I guess that could be another question. Feel free to link it here and I will have a look